# Remove files without string in name

Tags: bash, filenames, rm, macos

I want to remove files that have not the string `999` in their name.

I have tried:

```
grep -vlr 999 . | xargs -0 rm -f --
find . -print0 | grep --null-data -v 999 | xargs -0 rm --
```

But none of them works. I am using macOS Sierra, with bash: 3.2.57.

Comment: `grep -l` causes it to list the files where a match was found (or not found with `-v`) in the *content*, not the filename. `grep` always matches against the content of the files you specify, never their names.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using an extended globbing pattern in `bash`:

```
rm ./!(*999*)
```

This requires `shopt -s extglob` to be enabled (and for safety, also `shopt -s failglob`, so that no file with the unusual name `!(*999*)` gets removed by mistake if all filenames contain `999`). The pattern `!(*999*)` will match any name in the current directory, except those names matching `*999*`.

To also remove hidden files (files whose name starts with a *dot*), enable the `dotglob` option with `shopt -s dotglob`.

To only care about regular files or symbolic links to regular files (not directories etc.):

```
for name in ./!(*999*); do [ -f "$name" ] && rm "$name"; done
```

---

The `zsh` shell equivalent to the above loop would be

```
rm ./(^(*999*))(.)
```

---

Your first command will not work since `grep` will look inside files.  It would remove all files that have lines without `999` in them (had you added the `--null` option so it works with `xargs -0`).

Your second command will not work since `grep` on macOS does not support `--null-data` (it does however have a `--null` option, but only for when generating filename output). Also note that it would look for `999` anywhere in the file's *pathname* (i.e. including any directory components), not only the file's name.

Answer (score 21):

Just invert the name condition in `find` :

```
find . -type f \! -name "*999*"
```

Add `-delete` or `-exec rm {} +` to actually remove the matched files.

Comment: `!` is safe in `bash`.

Comment: One should be aware that this will also reach out to all files in any subdirectories.